# ES6+ Javascript Compression in .NET

Tags: .net, minify, bundling-and-minification

What are the current best options for compressing modern Javascript with .NET?

YUICompressor.NET and its Dependency EcmaScript.NET are both far behind the times in terms of modern ECMAScript version support. I can't find anything else thats being maintained either :(

I'm happy to contribute to projects to get them to where they need to be, but whats my best starting point?

I need to be able to compress JS from .NET itself. I don't mind PInvoking some dll, but "just use `<insert node-js package name here>`" is not a solution.

Comment: Use whatever you like. ASP.NET MVC projects started using task runners like Gulp and Grunt some years ago. Chek the docs : [Bundle and minify static assets in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x), [Use Gulp in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-gulp?view=aspnetcore-2.1) etc. The ability was definitely there in 2015, can't remember if it was in 2012 as well

Comment: Glad I can use whatever I like. Also good job on completely ignoring the critical part of the question "needs to be invokable from .NET" (and not `shell`ing it)

Comment: Then you have to explain the problem and why you want it to be invoked from .NET, since the common worklfow is to minify the tools at build time. Do you want to compress *dynamically generated* Javascript? Why can't that work with the build tools? ASP.NET *does* use Node for building Javascript

Comment: BTW `YUICompressor` is a node package. You probably meant YUICompressor.NET which, as I see, stopped being developed around the time VS came out with support for Grunt, Gulp, LESS etc. Eve Mads Kristensen's [WebCompiler](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler) seems inactive

Comment: If you were to ask one of the tool authors the same question, they'd ask you back "Why don't you use a task runner?". Only then would they be able to asnwer "then use XYZ". Perhaps you need the [JavascriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) package for an SPA? Or use [Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices) directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nuglify](https://github.com/trullock/NUglify/) is the answer, it has full ES2020/2021 support at the time of writing.

Disclaimer, I maintain this project. But I maintain it because of my need in this original question :D

Comment: This is great, Andrew. Our project uses standard 2014~era BundleConfig/ScriptBundle run-time minifcation via System.Web.Optimization. Unfortunately, we're encountering more ES6+ code snippets which don't minify well. We can manually prepare the .min.js files, but I would also like to avoid adding a whole npm/gulp toolchain just for minification. All this to ask: ... Can you suggest a simple way to link Nuglify into a standard RegisterBundles use case?

Comment: Does BundlerMinifier do what you want? Beware its probably using an old NUglify by default

Comment: Doesn't look like it, still an offline/build time bundler rather than runtime like the old built-in RegisterBundles stuff we're using. Our project uses .NET Framework 4.8, by the way. So we ended up just pre-minifying our ES6 script to a .min.js file. If we get more of these, we will probably have to overhaul our toolchain to do it the new/recommended way using a toolchain.